# python imaplib to get gmail inbox subjects titles and sender name

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib, email-headers

I'm using pythons imaplib to connect to my gmail account.  I want to retrieve the top 15 messages (unread or read, it doesn't matter) and display just the subjects and sender name (or address) but don't know how to display the contents of the inbox.

Here is my code so far (successful connection)

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('mygmail@gmail.com', 'somecrazypassword')
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')

#need to add some stuff in here

mail.logout()
```

I believe this should be simple enough, I'm just not familiar enough with the commands for the imaplib library.  Any help would be must appreciated...

**UPDATE**
thanks to Julian I can iterate through each message and retrieve the entire contents with:

```
typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
   typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
   print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
mail.close()
```

but I'm wanting just the subject and the sender. Is there a imaplib command for these items or will I have to parse the entire contents of data[0][1] for the text: Subject, and Sender?

**UPDATE**
OK, got the subject and sender part working but the iteration (1, 15) is done by desc order apparently showing me the oldest messages first.  How can I change this?  I tried doing this:

```
for i in range( len(data[0])-15, len(data[0]) ):
     print data
```

but that just gives me `None` for all 15 iterations... any ideas? I've also tried `mail.sort('REVERSE DATE', 'UTF-8', 'ALL')` but gmail doesnt support the .sort() function

**UPDATE**
Figured out a way to do it:

```
#....^other code is the same as above except need to import email module
mail.select('inbox')
typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
#get the most recent email id
latest_email_id = int( id_list[-1] )

#iterate through 15 messages in decending order starting with latest_email_id
#the '-1' dictates reverse looping order
for i in range( latest_email_id, latest_email_id-15, -1 ):
   typ, data = mail.fetch( i, '(RFC822)' )

   for response_part in data:
      if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
          msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
          varSubject = msg['subject']
          varFrom = msg['from']

   #remove the brackets around the sender email address
   varFrom = varFrom.replace('<', '')
   varFrom = varFrom.replace('>', '')

   #add ellipsis (...) if subject length is greater than 35 characters
   if len( varSubject ) > 35:
      varSubject = varSubject[0:32] + '...'

   print '[' + varFrom.split()[-1] + '] ' + varSubject
```

this gives me the most recent 15 message subject and sender address in decending order as requested! Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: The example from the Python docs works fine for me: http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib#imap4-example

Comment: Yes, your are right, that does work quiet well for retrieving full message content of all messages.  I just want the subject and the sender address though. I can then make the for loop just 1 through 15

Comment: And another link to the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/email.html ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
    c.select('INBOX', readonly=True)

    for i in range(1, 30):
        typ, msg_data = c.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                for header in [ 'subject', 'to', 'from' ]:
                    print '%-8s: %s' % (header.upper(), msg[header])
```

This should give you an idea on how to retrieve the subject and from?

Comment: what is email? are you referring to my 'mail' variable? and what is message_from_string() is that made up? I'm getting an error stating `AttributeError("Unknown IMAP4 command: '%s'" % attr)
AttributeError: Unknown IMAP4 command: 'message_from_string'`

Comment: nevermind, figured it out, I didn't include the email module. thanks

Comment: Would the code not raise an Exception in the case where there are less than 30 emails? `c.fetch()` would trigger the exception if the email id (`str(i)` in this case) does not exist.

Comment: @chutsu It coult, most likely you would just get a message from the server stating that there is no such ID. Depending on your library ofc.

Comment: I tested the code and it does in deed raise an exception if the email id (first argument in `c.fetch()` function) reaches 0, a simple fix would be to break the loop once the email id reaches 0. (email id don't seem to start from 0)

Comment: @chutsu except my code goes from 1 -> 30? How would it even hit 0, are you sure you tried this particular code? Also which mail-providers have you tried? I think 0 is indeed a index in some providers?

Comment: @Torxed Opps, I was using the OP's updated code which does indeed tread into 0 because of this line `for i in range( latest_email_id, latest_email_id-15, -1)`, so if `latest_email_id` is less than 15 the loop will go towards 0.

I also had a look at the RFC for IMAP 4 and can confirm that email sequence numbers start from 1, not 0. ([source here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.2))

Comment: @chutsu glad to hear and good to know. However from experience the RFC's is more like a guide-line than a actual implementation. There's a lot of "Should.." and "might.." in the RFC's and the developers go a little "meeeh, this isn't that important" when they produce things. But never the less, OP should strive to follow the RFC for sure, just bare in mind that others might not :)

Comment: @Torxed Lets say that I have an email and it contains multiple attachments and I want to see the names of the attachments. How can I do that using your code snippet?

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza I don't know of the top of my head. Use the code, and see what other propeties is in there other than `subject`, `to`, and `from`

Answer (score 11):

This was my solution to get the useful bits of information from emails:

```
import datetime
import email
import imaplib
import mailbox


EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "your@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "your password"

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN") # (ALL/UNSEEN)
i = len(data[0].split())

for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
    result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    # result, email_data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen') 
    # this might work to set flag to seen, if it doesn't already
    raw_email = email_data[0][1]
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    # Header Details
    date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
    if date_tuple:
        local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
        local_message_date = "%s" %(str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
    email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
    email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
    subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

    # Body details
    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            file_name = "email_" + str(x) + ".txt"
            output_file = open(file_name, 'w')
            output_file.write("From: %s\nTo: %s\nDate: %s\nSubject: %s\n\nBody: \n\n%s" %(email_from, email_to,local_message_date, subject, body.decode('utf-8')))
            output_file.close()
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 7):

For those looking for how to check mail and parse the headers, this is what I used:

```
def parse_header(str_after, checkli_name, mailbox) :
    #typ, data = m.search(None,'SENTON', str_after)
    print mailbox
    m.SELECT(mailbox)
    date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    #date = (datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
    #date = "23-Jul-2012"

    print date
    result, data = m.uid('search', None, '(SENTON %s)' % date)
    print data

    doneli = []
    for latest_email_uid in data[0].split():
        print latest_email_uid
        result, data = m.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = data[0][1]

        import email
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
        print email_message['To']
        print email_message['Subject']
        print email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['From'])
        print email_message.items() # print all headers
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'message_from_string'. I'm importing email, promise.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts you need to use `from email import email`. I presume you used `import email` which means you're trying to access `message_from_string` at the wrong level.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a ready made simple script to list last inbox via IMAP without sorting through all messages. The information here is useful, though DIY and misses some aspects. First, [`IMAP4.select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.select) returns message count. Second, subject header decoding isn't straightforward.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import HTMLParser


# to unescape xml entities
_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

def decodeHeader(value):
  if value.startswith('"=?'):
    value = value.replace('"', '')

  value, encoding = decode_header(value)[0]
  if encoding:
    value = value.decode(encoding)

  return _parser.unescape(value)

def listLastInbox(top = 4):
  mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
  mailbox.login('mygmail@gmail.com', 'somecrazypassword')

  selected = mailbox.select('INBOX')
  assert selected[0] == 'OK'
  messageCount = int(selected[1][0])

  for i in range(messageCount, messageCount - top, -1):
    reponse = mailbox.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')[1]
    for part in reponse:
      if isinstance(part, tuple):
        message = email.message_from_string(part[1])
        yield {h: decodeHeader(message[h]) for h in ('subject', 'from', 'date')}

  mailbox.logout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  for message in listLastInbox():
    print '-' * 40
    for h, v in message.items():
      print u'{0:8s}: {1}'.format(h.upper(), v)
```

Answer (score 3):

`BODY` gets almost everything and marks the message as read.
    `BODY[<parts>]` gets just those parts.
    `BODY.PEEK[<parts>]` gets the same parts, but doesn't mark the message read.
    `<parts>` can be `HEADER` or `TEXT` or `HEADER.FIELDS (<list of fields>)` or 
    `HEADER.FIELDS.NOT (<list of fields>)`

This is what I use: `typ, data = connection.fetch(message_num_s, b'(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])')`

`

```
def safe_encode(seq):
    if seq not in (list,tuple):
        seq = [seq]
    for i in seq:
        if isinstance(i, (int,float)):
            yield str(i).encode()
        elif isinstance(i, str):
            yield i.encode()
        elif isinstance(i, bytes):
            yield i
        else:
            raise ValueError

def fetch_fields(connection, message_num, field_s):
    """Fetch just the fields we care about. Parse them into a dict"""
    if isinstance(field_s, (list,tuple)):
        field_s = b' '.join(safe_encode(field_s))
    else:
        field_s = tuple(safe_encode(field_s))[0]

    message_num = tuple(safe_encode(message_num))[0]

    typ, data = connection.fetch(message_num, b'(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (%s)])'%(field_s.upper()))
    if typ != 'OK':
        return typ, data  #change this to an exception if you'd rather

    items={}
    lastkey = None
    for line in data[0][1].splitlines():
        if b':' in line:
            lastkey, value = line.strip().split(b':', 1)
            lastkey = lastkey.capitalize()
            #not all servers capitalize the same, and some just leave it
            #as however it arrived from some other mail server.

            items[lastkey]=value
        else:
            #subject was so long it ran onto the next line, luckily it didn't have a ':' in it so its easy to recognize.
            items[lastkey]+=line
            #print(items[lastkey])
    return typ, items
`
```

You drop it into your code example: by replacing the call to 'mail.fetch()' with `fetch_fields(mail, i, 'SUBJECT FROM')` or `fetch_fields(mail, i, ('SUBJECT' 'FROM'))`

Comment: All the other answers fetch the entire message - e.g. `mail.fetch( i, '(RFC822)' )` - which is expensive and slow. I believe this is the only answer that actually applies IMAPv4rev1 as it was designed.

Comment: I can't believe this is the lowest-scoring answer. `decode_header` and `make_header` from the `email.header` module will assemble and decode the header for you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to all the above answers.

```
import imaplib
import base64
import os
import email

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email_user = "email@domain.com"
    email_pass = "********"
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("hostname", 993)
    mail.login(email_user, email_pass)
    mail.select()
    type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0].decode('utf-8')
    id_list = mail_ids.split()
    mail.select('INBOX', readonly=True)
    for i in id_list:
        typ, msg_data = mail.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                print(msg['from']+"\t"+msg['subject'])
```

This will give you the email's from and subject name.