# Retrieve new emails

Tags: python, email

I was wondering is there a way to get all unreaded email using Python?
I searched here but all I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314942/python-imaplib-to-get-gmail-inbox-subjects-titles-and-sender-name),
but I didn't understand answers.
Could we use imap4 for this?

All I could done was using

```
import imaplib

mailserver=imaplib.IMAP4.SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com:993')
mailserver.login('somthing','somthing')
status, count=mailserver.select('inbox')
status, data=mailserver.fetch(count[0], '(UID BODY[TEXT])')

print (data[0][1])

mailserver.close()
mailserver.logout()
```

and fetch the last email fron inbox like all of the tutorials shows

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for only unread messages, you are going to have to search your inbox for the unread messages. More like this:

```
(status, data) = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if status == 'OK':
   for num in data[0].split():
      #do something about your email
```

Comment: sorry, but it didn't work :(. Could you explain more?